# Getting a "403 access denied" error instead of serving file (using django, gunicorn nginx)

Tags: nginx, redirect, django, http-status-code-403, gunicorn

Getting a "403 access denied" error instead of serving file (using django, gunicorn nginx)

I am attempting to use nginx to serve private files from django. For X-Access-Redirect settings I followed the following guide

http://www.chicagodjango.com/blog/permission-based-file-serving/

Here is my site config file (/etc/nginx/site-available/sitename):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    server_name localhost;

    client_max_body_size    50M;

    ssl_certificate /home/user/site.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/site.key;

    access_log /home/user/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /home/user/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
           access_log /home/user/gunicorn/access.log;
           error_log /home/user/gunicorn/error.log;
           alias /path_to/app;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
           proxy_connect_timeout 100s;
           proxy_send_timeout 100s;
           proxy_read_timeout 100s;
    }

    location /protected/ {
            internal;
            alias /home/user/protected;
    }
}
```

I then tried using the following in my django view to test the download:

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['Content-Type'] = "application/zip"
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected/test.zip'
return response
```

but instead of the file download I get:

**403 Forbidden

nginx/1.1.19**

**Please note:** I have removed all the personal data from the the config file, so if there are any obvious mistakes not related to my error that is probably why.

My nginx error log gives me the following:

```
**2012/09/18 13:44:36 [error] 23705#0: *44 directory index of "/home/user/protected/" is forbidden, client: 80.221.147.225, server: localhost, request: "GET /icbdazzled/tmpdir/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.icb.fi"**
```

Comment: can you post what your error log says when you make a request?

Comment: @Mike. Thanks for responding, I have now added the output from the nginx error log to my question. There is no error output from gunicorn.

Comment: The only output when i run gunicorn in debug mode is "[debug]x_forwarded_for_header: X-FORWARDED-FOR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `root`:

```
location /protected/ {
        internal;
        root /home/user;
}
```

instead of your `alias`:

```
location /protected/ {
        internal;
        alias /home/user/protected;
}
```

Comment: This seems to have had some effect, but now I am getting a 404 error. If I tried testing the view without the "X-Accel-Redirect" statement and the view url is working so it like it is a file referencing issue.

Comment: I was under the impression that using root inside a location block was not considere best practice?

Comment: Using `alias` instead of `root` is a bad practice. Official documentation [recommends `root` where it's possible](http://nginx.org/r/alias). But to be more precise your problem was missing `/` at the end of `alias` path while the `location` has it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435124/nginx-mapping-for-static-files-and-reverse-proxy/12437975#12437975) for details.

Comment: I have it working now. It ended up being a combination of issues. The first being  the use of alias instead of root, and the second being the file/folder permissions. To serve files from a folder permissions MUST be set to the same as the server (in my case gunicorn, but its probably the same for other server setups)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue no long ago. It might be a combination of factors. I found how to fix `403 access denied` by replacing the user in the `nginx.conf` file.

- I deployed my website on an ubuntu server using Digital Ocean.
- I created a new user on my new ubuntu server and give admin priviliges

```sh
    adduser newuser

    usermod -aG sudo newuser
```

- I updated my new server and installed few packages

```sh
    sudo apt update

    sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib nginx curl
```

- I followed all this beautiful instruction on [how to deploy your site on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- Since I changed the user and I ssh into my new server using this new user, I need to replace the user on the `nginx.conf`. By default `nginx.conf` user is `www-data`:

```sh
    user www-data;

    worker_processes auto;

    pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

Then I replaced with my sudo user and solved my problem.

```sh
    user newuser;

    worker_processes auto;

    pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

- Then I restart nginx, gunicorn and postgresql(even if the last one it is not really necessary)

```sh
    sudo systemctl restart nginx 

    sudo systemctl restart gunicorn

    sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

And tada.. :) no more issue.